# Analytics for Bada applications

Tags: analytics, bada, integrate

I am trying to add an analytics service in my Bada application.
It's a C++ application , not a web one.

Google analytics only supports Android and iPhone as far as I've seen.
Is there any way to integrate it anyway?

Or is there other analytics services that are free and could be integrated?

Thank you,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest way is to add an invisible WebPanel where you load the HTML/JS-code for Google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question, but take a look on http://deskmetrics.com. They have analytics for non web apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Piwik for analytics. You need to setup a Piwik Server for that and call its APIs.

Check for more details.

http://piwik.org/blog/2010/07/new-piwik-tracking-api-track-visits-from-mobile-apps-desktop-apps-anywhere/